# Vacation and vacations

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

> 1)Summer and Winter **vacation** are compulsory in our schools.
>
> 2)Summer and Winter **vacations** are compulsory in our schools.

Which is correct? If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Comment: The second sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

They definitely both work. You might hear/read either.

I'm not sure I can help much with the difference in meaning. They are essentially the same.

The first, using the singular *vacation* rather than the plural *vacations*, might allow for the idea that you are talking *only* about this year's Summer and Winter vacation. Unlikely. Perhaps barely possible.

The second is clearly talking about any vacation, for this year or any other year.

Both the first and second are implying (which is to say, omitting) one word:

- Summer *vacation* and Winter vacation are compulsory in our schools.
- Summer *vacations* and Winter vacations are compulsory in our schools.

The first `vacation` is a bit repetitive and can be omitted, or so I suppose would be the proper way to think of it.

If there really is a single thing called "Summer and Winter vacation" (which I would judge to be highly unlikely), then there is no implication, no omitted word, no parallelism!